# Generate self signed RSA-2048-SHA-256 certificate PFX file using openSSL

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, rsa, sha

I am trying to create a self signed RSA-2048-SHA-256 certificate PFX file, in order to use it for data signing in my WCF requests.

I used some openSSL examples in order to create a certificate PFX file, but even  though I set the SHA algorithm to 256, when I load it in my .net app, I see that this certificate's private key, has these settings:

```
KeyExchangeAlgorithm = RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx

SignatureAlgorithm = http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
```

and when I use the code below in order to consume this certificate, I am getting "Invalid algorithm specified exception", but if I change the SHA256CryptoServiceProvider to SHA1CryptoServiceProvider everything works fine.

```
string msg = "This is my test message";

X509Certificate2 privateCert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\TEMP\\private.pfx", "12345");

byte[] signature = (privateCert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider).SignData(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(msg), new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider());
```

I can only assume that my certificate file was not created with SHA256, but instead with some kind of default SHA1 algorithm.

Those are the steps I used in order to create my certificate:

1. `openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem`
2. `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out private.pfx`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As for why you can't create new SHA-256-based signatures with the key, either add `-CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider”` to the pkcs12 command, or get the private key from `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()`.  But that's really a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I used -CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider” in my pkcs12 command, and now it works, i actually tried this approach before, but for some reason the pkcs12 command failed. I also tried to use cert.GetRSAPrivateKey(), and this worked as well, although it requires .NET Framework 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Believing that those two properties have meaning :).

The two values you're seeing are [hard-coded into RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsacryptoserviceprovider.cs,ade983854eda2cc5).  Other RSA types (such as RSACng) have [different, less confusing, hard-coded values](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsa.cs,3cbb52d748deed2b).

The problem is that a key doesn't have either of those attributes.  A key can be used for multiple purposes (though NIST recommends against it). A TLS session (or EnvelopedCMS document, etc) can have a key exchange algorithm. A certificate, SignedCMS document, or other such material can have a signature (and thus a signature algorithm).

To know that your certificate was signed with RSA-PKCS1-SHA256 you need to look at [X509Certificate2.SignatureAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.signaturealgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
switch (cert.SignatureAlgorithm.Value)
{
    case "1.2.840.113549.1.1.4":
        return "RSA-PKCS1-MD5";
    case "1.2.840.113549.1.1.5";
        return "RSA-PKCS1-SHA1";
    case "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11";
        return "RSA-PKCS1-SHA2-256"; // Winner
    case "1.2.840.113549.1.1.12":
        return "RSA-PKCS1-SHA2-384";
    case "1.2.840.113549.1.1.13":
        return "RSA-PKCS1-SHA2-512";
    default:
        throw new SomethingFromTheFutureOrMaybeNotRSAException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i checked my certificate using the cert.SignatureAlgorithm valie, and indeed, as you said, it was actually RSA-PKCS1-SHA2-256 :).