# Self-signed certificate in .NET, changing signing algorithm from SHA-1 to something else

Tags: .net, .net-core, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I got a splendid answer on creating a self-signed certificate to be consumed by Azure principals at [Generating self-signed certificate without external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240640/1332416)
 by the excellent [bartonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535399/bartonjs).

The following is the pretty much the code provided in the Azure sample. However, I'm stuck at that how could the signing algorithm be changed? It seem to be SHA-1 by default, I might be wrong, but perhaps this should be explicitly be set to something else like SHA-256.

```
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedRsaCertificate(string subjectName, string friendlyName)
    {
        if(subjectName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subjectName));
        }

        if(friendlyName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(friendlyName));
        }

        var keyParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters();
        keyParams.Parameters.Add(new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(2048), CngPropertyOptions.Persist));
        using(var rsaKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), keyParams))
        {
            using(RSA rsa = new RSACng(rsaKey))
            {
                var certRequest = new CertificateRequest(subjectName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                //Explicitly not a CA.
                certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

                certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment, true));

                //TLS Server EKU.
                certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

                //SubjectAlternativeName extension.
                var sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
                sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost");
                certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

                DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                var certificate = certRequest.CreateSelfSigned(notBefore: now, notAfter: now.AddDays(1)/*now.AddDays(365.25)*/);
                certificate.FriendlyName = friendlyName;

                return certificate;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code from bartonjs works fine. Yours does not even compile. I tried SHA256 and SHA512 and the signature algorithm in the self-signed certificate is sha256RSA or sha512RSA.

Comment: The argument between the key and the signature padding (in this case SHA512) determines the hash into the signature algorithm, so this would be RSA-SSA-PKCS1_1.5-SHA-2-512.  The `Thumbprint` value will still be SHA-1, because the thumbprint is defined to be the SHA-1 of the signed certificate.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe I should've added I was looking this through `certlm` well past last night. The third lowest point tells  "signing algorithm" in my language (not English), so I assumed that would be used in signing. I think this answers it. There's another one too, "the hash algorithm of the signature", which is "sha512" and a third one "the signing hash algorithm", which is "sha512rsa". It looks like all is well then.